# Rally Rest Api: Get User's Email Address from Defect

Tags: java, rally

With Rally's rest api, how can I query to find a user's email address?

For instance, I have this query to get a defect which contains the full name of the user who opened it and the user who owns the defect:

```
 QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("defect");
 defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Project", "LastUpdateDate", "FormattedId"));
 defectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Project.Name", "=", rallyProjectName).and(new QueryFilter("LastUpdateDate", ">", defectTimestamp.getTimestamp())));
 QueryResponse projectDefects = rallyApi.query(defectRequest);
```

Now I'd like to take the Submitted By and Owner users from the defect and get their email addresses.

Comment: I think you'd have to add those 2 fields to your fetch, and then those properties should be available through your QueryResponse.

Comment: The fetch is working to get the names of the owner and submitted by users, but their names don't contain their email addresses; so I assumed that a new query would be needed that was just on their names. I've tried this without success: `QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("user");
            userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Email"));
            userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("User.Name", "=", "Joe User"));
            QueryResponse user = rallyApi.query(userRequest);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain to include the fields "Owner" and "SubmittedBy" on your Fetch for the Defects:

```
   defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Project", "LastUpdateDate", "FormattedId", "Owner", "SubmittedBy"));
```

Then the Owner and SubmittedBy fields on each returned Defect (if populated in Rally and not null) will have a reference to the corresponding User object in Rally. Then your inclination to do a second request for this is spot on. It's easiest to just use that ref and do a GetRequest straight against the ref. Here's how on the Owner field as an example (forgive the clumsy try/catch block - it's catching empty Owner fields):

```
        QueryResponse projectDefects = restApi.query(defectRequest);
        if (projectDefects.wasSuccessful()) {
            for (JsonElement result : projectDefects.getResults()) {
                JsonObject defect = result.getAsJsonObject();
                try {
                    JsonObject ownerJsonObject = defect.get("Owner").getAsJsonObject();
                    String ownerRef = ownerJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
                    GetRequest ownerRequest = new GetRequest(ownerRef);
                    GetResponse ownerResponse = restApi.get(ownerRequest);
                    JsonObject ownerObj = ownerResponse.getObject();
                    System.out.println(String.format("Read owner. EmailAddress = %s",
                            ownerObj.get("EmailAddress").getAsString()));
                } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ise) {
                    // System.out.println("IllegalStateException caught: ");
                    // ise.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```